# What does the ByteCode mean from javacore file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

Normally, when walking through the javacore file, we can see code stack as below:

```
at com/csii/pe/channel/http/servlet/MainServlet.doGet(Bytecode PC:78(Compiled Code))
at javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743(Compiled Code))
at javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856(Compiled Code))
```

As for the word **Bytecode** above, does it mean the code is from the **self-developed application** rather than the **Middleware** inside like IBM WAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> As for the word Bytecode above, does it mean the code is from the self-developed application rather than the Middleware inside like IBM WAS?

I don't think so.  I think you are misparsing it ... and it is saying that the bytecode program counter (PC) was 78 at that point.

(However, fully qualified class / method name are a give away ...)